# Angular show / hide with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to fade out a div and then show a new div but my code is broken.  How can I fix? The fade-out animation works but the showManagement div does not appear.

HTML

```
<div ng-hide="hidden" ng-class="{fade: startFade}">
    <p>this is start content that should be faded</p>
</div>
<div class="showManagement" ng-show="showManagement">
    <p>this is the new content to be displayed once the fade is complete.</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.getManagement = function () {

    $scope.startFade = true;

    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.hidden = true;
    }, 2000);

    // this is the part that doesn't display
    $scope.showManagement = true;
 };
```

CSS

```
.fade{
    transition: opacity 3s;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: have you looked into ng-animate? it adds classes on-before for ng-hide, on ng-repeat, ng-switch

Comment: @Aaron is right, you should try to leverage on ngAnimate service. If you do want to solve the issue with the way you provide, you may refer to the example I provided below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide your controller and didn't show where you call the function `getManagement()`, I'll assume that you want all the fade-out fade-in events show within 2 seconds after angular loaded.

Here's an [example on CodePen](http://codepen.io/kavare/pen/vOYNLP) for how you can achieve your goal with your approach.

And here's the code:

#### HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="wrapper" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-class="{fade: startFade}">
        <p>this is start content that should be faded</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-class="{hideManagement: hideManagement, showManagement: showManagement}">
        <p>this is the new content to be displayed once the fade is complete.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

#### CSS

```
.fade{
    transition: opacity 3s;
    opacity: 0;
}

.hideManagement {
  opacity: 0;
}

.showManagement {
    transition: opacity 3s 3s;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

#### JS

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.startFade = false;
    $scope.showManagement = false;
    $scope.hideManagement = true;

    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.startFade = true;
      $scope.showManagement = true;
      $scope.hideManagement = false;
    }, 2000);
  }]);
```

A few things you have to keep in mind:

1. You cannot animate your `display: none;` and `display: block;` with CSS3 transition. This is the reason why `ng-hide` in your `.showManagement`  is not showing with transition effect. You should keep using `opacity` to achieve this goal, just like you did in `ng-class="{fade: startFade}"`
2. Initialize your state at the beginning of your Angular controller. In the example your provide, it's a little bit confusing how you set your `$scope.showManagement`, `$scope.hidden`, and `$scope.startFade`. Once you setup your initial state like the example I provide, it would be more clear that what kind of states change you should make in the function, whether it's in a `$timeout` callback or some other functions trigger by other events
3. To make `.showManagement`  fade-in right after the first `<div>` finishing it's fade-out effect, you may set the delay in css transition.

If you are doing more complex animation, you should try leveraging on `ngAnimate` service. With ngAnimate, you can get rid of those `ng-class` in this example, and simply binding your animation rules with `.ng-enter`, `.ng-enter-active`, `.ng-hide`, `.ng-hide-active`, which are automatically bind to your elements by Angular. Here's the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) for `ngAnimate`.